# Typo3: How to insert the Page Title dynamically into the Description meta tag

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, typoscript, page-title

Using the Introduction Package 4.5
(Not templa voila)

The page.meta template sets the meta tag 'description' in Setup:

```
page.meta {
description = {$plugin.meta.description}
}
```

. . . and the description string value is defined in the root template Constant:

```
plugin.meta {
description = description string goes here
}
```

But now how do I dynamically include each Page Title in the Description meta tag?
Something like

```
 description = {plugin.meta.description}{pageTitle.value} ?
```

Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: If one of the answers worked for you, do not forget to mark them as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put this in a single line you could use .dataWrap on description like this:

```
page.meta.description.dataWrap = {$plugin.meta.description} - {field:title}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any stdWrap function on `description`, I would use a COA to combine those values:

```
page.meta.description.cObject = COA
page.meta.description.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = {$plugin.meta.description}

    20 = TEXT
    20.data = field:title
}
```

You can find more information here: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/META

Comment: I think you would need to make it: `page.meta.description.cObject = COA` and `page.meta.description.cObject {`

Comment: And change `20.data = field.title` to `20.data = field:title` or `20.field = title`.

Comment: Thank you BjörnKuipers and konsolenfreddy. Works perfectly!

Comment: Great @konsolenfreddy, thanks for updating your example :) Sure HowardK, np